# Ideal membership problem for monomial ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

[image]

Hi guys. I'd really appreciate help on understanding the proof for this Lemma above. I'm not sure how we got: "we see that every term on the right side of the equation is divisible by some x^{a(i)}. Hence, the left side x^b must have the same property."

I don't see how we can factor some x^{a(i)} from the summation in the right side of the equation. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: There is no factorization needed. The whole point is that the monomials form a basis (of vector space) over $k$  for the polynomial ring $k[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$.

Comment: I agree with this. But I don't see how there exists some i such that x^{a(i)} divides x^b.